# Is there a Kotlin functon for finding the index of an element in the vector?

Tags: kotlin

In python, I can use index to find the index of an element, such as:

```
   # vowels list
    vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'i', 'u']
    
    # index of 'e'
    index = vowels.index('e')
    print('The index of e:', index)
    
    # index of the first 'i'
    index = vowels.index('i')
    print('The index of i:', index)
```

Is there an equivalent function in Kotlin ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there's [`indexOf()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/index-of.html), which is an extension function declared on `Iterable`, `List` and many (probably all) array types.

Comment: only Iterables and list,no vectors?

Comment: By "vectors" you mean `java.util.Vector`? It implements `Iterable` so it should work.